# How can I force user to use methods to change the Class Fields , and do not change it directly?

Tags: c#, oop

I am a VBA developer and new to C#
Below is my Employee Class :

```
class Employee
{
   public string name;

   public Employee()
    {
       age = 0;
    }

    public void setName(string newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }  
}
```

When I create an object of my Employeeclass, I can either use the method provided to set the value of name

```
Employee E1 = new Employee();
E1.setName("Name 1");
```

or I can set the name directly.

```
Employee E1 = new Employee();
E1.name = "Name 1"
```

The whole point is How can I stop users to set the value of my fields directly / without calling my method , If you could please tell me how can I set the values of my class fields efficiently.

Comment: by making the fields private. [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) / [private (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private)

Comment: Make your fields/properties `private` instead of public, so that other functions outside the class can't access them

Answer (score 2):

Just use properties instead of (public) fields.

```
public class Employee
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            // Your setter-code here. Validation and stuff like that
            _name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would like to use a public property and make the field `private` like below. You don't need a separate setter method likewise you are doing

```
class Employee
{
   private string name;

   public Employee()
    {
       age = 0;
    }

    public string Name
    {
      get {return name; }   
      set { name = value; }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should define private member.

```
class Employee
{
   private string name;

    public void setName(string newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }  
}
```

NOTE: Private members of a class can only be accessed within class definition while public members can be accessed outside class by using its object.

Or, simply use Properties as,

```
class Employee
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

Using proerty, you can set Name as,

```
  Employee emp = new Employee();
  emp.Name = "suman";
```